# The code below in while-loop only the first row is updated field count, while I want all rows be done

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

```
<?php 
   if($action=='sefaresh'){
    $cookiname=$_COOKIE['mybasket'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `idsabad`,`cookiname`,`idmahsool`,`tedad`,`pardakht` FROM `sabad` WHERE `cookiname`=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $cookiname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($idsabad11, $cookiname1, $idmahsool1, $tedad1, $pardakht1);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $id = $idsabad11;
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `sabad` SET `tedad`=? WHERE `idsabad`=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $_POST['tedad'.$idmahsool1], $id );
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this question is so unclear, it's not funny.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the statement object `$stmt`. You're overwriting the outer statement object `$stmt` inside `while()` loop to do your `UPDATE` operation i.e this statement `$db->prepare("UPDATE`sabad`SET ...` inside the `while()` will return a *different* statement object which you're assigning to `$stmt`, thereby overwriting the original/outer `$stmt`. And this is why one row is getting updated.

So change your `while()` loop in the following way,

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $id = $idsabad11;
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `sabad` SET `tedad`=? WHERE `idsabad`=?");
    $stmt1->bind_param("ii", $_POST['tedad'.$idmahsool1], $id );
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->close();
}
```

Comment: Thank for Answer. very good